# SQL query is not throwing exception in mule when has to throw an exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, mule, mule-component, mule-el

My SQL query contains update and insert statement. I am providing bad input data for SQL query to throw an exception. If it executes update statement, it is throwing exception whereas insert statement is not throwing when it has to ideally throw an exception.The length of "UOM" field is 5, but in the input i am giving length more than 5 (i.e "inches"). So ideally it should throw "String or binary data would be truncated." exception but it throwing only in case of "update" statement.

Query

```
UPDATE dbo.ix_spc_product
SET DBStatus = 1, UPC ='101', Name='null',
Width=2.750, Height=2.560, Depth =1.440, AbbrevName ='null',
Size = 1, UOM ='Inches' WHERE ID='123450'

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0   
INSERT INTO dbo.ix_spc_product
(DBStatus,UPC, ID, Name, Width, Height, Depth, AbbrevName, Size, UOM)
VALUES (1,'101','123450','null',2.750,2.560,1.440,'null',1,'Inches')
```

Comment: A simple repro in SSMS with table variables shows that 2 errors are being thrown, both in `update` and `insert`. Are you sure you retrieve both exceptions on the client side?

Comment: And besides, such things should be done via `try / catch` block. Gives much more control.

Comment: If you manually execute the SQL commands outside of Mule, does MySQL generate an error message?

Comment: Yes, MySQL is generating error message whereas it is throwing exception in mule